# fread only reading 64 bytes?

Tags: c, fopen

As the title says, freads appears to only be reading the first 64 characters. Relevant code:

```
FILE* sigD = fopen("signature", "r");
char *sig[255];
fread(sig, 255, 255, sigD);
close(sigD);    
fputs(sig, stdout);
```

Console output:

```
user@PC:~$ ./a.out --has-sig 
;2F*S|tr;;E9;Yb=R6)!fcXhoX@RC`#NzLy<}w@T+uvH${3Et&9K&-0~%D{1
user@PC:~$ 
user@PC:~$ cat signature
;2F*S|tr;;E9;Yb=R6)!fcXhoX@RC`#NzLy<}w@T+uvH${3Et&9K&-0~%D{1N{7ry:-B9b:kGB=Gkk9V+Cc$8a&35W{15Q~#-+PMeqa;#cKA7Ew3G6P4smDdJWV2@>R!V#ki@(Xj<a,^B)qJ5D&bON//?%/!G)XA&m|8:1mVHmx{7nQoRJ%v{(K:;JtX2hOm/dhVm9mnuDMSbQX55ouVnmECbA`/`!?=Mh0Ab^@vk*K*HG5$omu6716/Loh1Ht
```

h
As that log shows, there is 254 characters in the file, but only 64 are getting read.

EDIT: problem wasn't with fread, I had accidentally written in zero-terminators into the file.

Comment: I imagine you should have fread(sig,sizeof(char),255, sigD) instead.

Comment: Why have you not bothered to check the return value from `fread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear if this is related, but there seems to be a couple problems:

```
char *sig[255];
fread(sig, 255, 255, sigD);
```

The call to `fread` is not consistent with the declaration.  It should maybe be the following (you probably want an array of char rather than an array of pointers to char).  And the size/nitems info passed to [fread](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/) was not correct:

```
char sig[255];
// initially I had this as 'sizeof(), 1' but I think for this file it would make
// more sense as the following (nitems=255):
fread(sig, 1, sizeof(sig), sigD);
```

And while it should not matter, you might try opening it with a mode of `"rb"` to force a binary open (the `b` for binary is supposed to be ignored on POSIX conforming systems).

Comment: Made all these edits, full 254 characters still not being printed.

Comment: @W00t:  After some thought, I reversed the order of the fread args (the  size and nitems params).  You might try that, but I suspect it won't make a difference.  And possibly add the 'b' to the mode ... but that also *should* not affect it.  Sorry - kind of vague here.

Comment: Changing r to rb had no effect. Other ideas?

Comment: @W00t:  What is the return value of the fread call (and what are the exact parameters)?  You might update your original post with your latest changes just to keep everyone on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of `sig` is incorrect. If you want an array of characters you must remove the asterisk. You have defined an array of character pointers.  It should look like:

```
char sig[255];
```